# How to update/install packages on offline linux machines

Tags: linux

I have an offline environment with a lot of Linux machine (about 10). One is Ubuntu and the rest are Oracle Linux. Now I can't connect any of those machines to the internet. But my pc is connected to the internet. I want to install packages on all those machines. So I want to know what is the best and fastest way to do this? Is there any tools that can help with this? Can I create some sort of a local repo machine and connect those machines to it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/linux/create-a-local-yum-repository-for-oracle-linux-8) page the procedure of creating offline repo for Oracle Linux is quite sample:

> ```
> dnf install -y dnf-utils
> ```
>
> Create the following directories to hold the main OS and UEK
> respoitories.
>
> ```
> mkdir -p /u01/repo/OracleLinux
> ```
>
> The reposync command is used to synchronize a remote yum repository to
> a local directory, using yum to retrieve the packages.
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/reposync --newest-only --download-metadata --repoid=ol8_baseos_latest -p /u01/repo/OracleLinux
> /usr/bin/reposync --newest-only --download-metadata --repoid=ol8_appstream -p /u01/repo/OracleLinux
> /usr/bin/reposync --newest-only --download-metadata --repoid=ol8_UEKR6 -p /u01/repo/OracleLinux
> ```

Comment: Great! I will use this when I start building the Oracle linux VMs. But currently I am stuck with this one Ubuntu machine. I will look for a similar way for Ubuntu.